# Questions on Random Variables and the Central Limit Theorem (CLT)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable, central-limit-theorem

I have some confusions regarding random variables and the CLT that I want to clarify. In this regard, are both the statements below, correct?

Note: In both statements, X1...Xn are i.i.d random variables.

Let Xi is the height of an individual belonging to a particular state. n such heights are recorded. Then, by CLT, the mean height of the n individuals tends to the true mean (of the population) as n->infinity.

Let Xi is the mean height of k individuals belonging to a particular state. These k individuals are drawn at random and the experiment is repeated n times, and n means are recorded. Then by CLT, the mean of the means tends to the true mean of the means (of the population) as n->infinity.

With regard to practical scenarios, when is #1 performed and when is #2 performed?

I have this confusion because most of the problems I see online are regarding 1 experiment, i.e. N numbers are recorded and we need to compute mean, variance, Confidence Interval of the mean, etc. However, when I read about the CLT, I see the "mean of means", i.e. some parameter is recorded from k samples drawn at random and the experiment is repeated n times, and then the convergence in distribution is explained.

I haven't taken a background probability class before and I am learning things in stats simultaneously, so I get confused at times. Kindly point out to relevant books/links I might need to revisit which can clarify this concept in case my question is too trivial.

Comment: The CLT doesn't say what you say it does; that's a Law of Large Numbers result.

Comment: You can find an exposition on convergence notions in Casella's and Berger's [Statistical Inference.](https://amzn.to/2mdzCrF)

Comment: The CLT does not apply to all distributions. For example there are the so called stable laws.